# Taskqeue fails after POST with "task1 failed to execute"

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce, task-queue

We're having an issue trying to run a Mapreduce job on the Google Appengine. We are running into an infinite error loop with no Tracebacks or debug information.

```
INFO     2014-02-08 20:12:38,877 module.py:612] default: "POST /mapreduce/pipeline/run HTTP/1.1" 404 52
WARNING  2014-02-08 20:12:38,877 taskqueue_stub.py:1980] Task task1 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.100 seconds
```

Here is the minimal code that produces the issue:

```
import webapp2 
from mapreduce_dependencies import base_handler
class SendEmailPipeline(base_handler.PipelineBase): pass
class MREmailHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self): SendEmailPipeline().start()
```

What is going on, and what are we missing? I have all of the code (including the original source if anyone's interested.) I can also run any debugging code you propose.

Thanks in advance, PythonNut

Comment: How about adding some logging.

Comment: Actually look at the first line, you are getting a 404 error, so the task is trying to execute but the URL handler hasn't been mapped to your code, hence the 404 and the task can't start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the mapreduce handlers in your app.yaml.

Assuming you downloaded the mapreduce library into your project root folder:

```
handlers:
- url: /mapreduce(/.*)?
  script: mapreduce.main.APP
  login: admin
```